# Auto Refresh on load page failure

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension for chrome that auto refreshes the page when the page load is failed for any reason.

my manifest.json:

```
{ "browser_action" : { "default_icon" : "icon.png"
    },
  "description" : "Making your first Google Chrome extension.",
  "icons" : { "128" : "icon.png" },
  "name" : "Tutorialzine Extension",
  "version" : "1.0", 
  "permissions": [
     "webRequest",
     "tabs",
     "<all_urls>"
   ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>","http://*/*","https://*/*","*://*/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

myscript.js :

```
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(function details){
    chrome.tabs.reload(details.tabId);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you make your extension? I am looking for such kind of extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content scripts don't have access to most of `chrome.*` APIs. It's clearly stated [in the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html):

```
However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
- Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)
```

You should use a [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) or [event page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) instead.

Also `chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(function details)` is not a valid JavaScript code. `function` keyword shouldn't be there. I believe you copied this code from docs, but in docs this type of pseudo-JavaScript is used only to describe function definition (what types of arguments it expects, what type of values does it return etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Since I'm not a pro @ chrome extensions, I'd be very thankful if someone could show me exactly how to work with background/events page.

Comment: I think that docs will be happy to explain you that :) Also check out the [samples](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html).

Comment: I wish I had the time for that ;{

Comment: And I wish I had time to teach you how to use background pages :( Programming is mostly about learning all the time, if you don't have time to that just hire someone.

Comment: How much you want for this? :) I guess that's very simple for you.

Comment: [Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8989748/autoRefreshExt.zip), and be sure to donate something extra to charity this year. I modified your code to work, it reloads a page after 1s if error occurs, you can try it by going to some nonexistent domain ie. http://xsfwer.com/

Comment: Thanks you very much. I'm willing to donate $20 for that. Is there any website I can do that, for charity?

Comment: I like [Girls Who Code](https://www.redditdonate.com/donate/59), thanks for donating! I hope this extension will do the trick for you.